# IJVM ILOAD instruction does not load proper value

Tags: java, assembly, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am writing a simple program to compute the absolute value of a few integers in IJVM for the MIC1 architecture. I am using the emulator located [here](http://www.ontko.com/mic1/).

Here is the code:

```
BIPUSH 0xC0  
DUP
ISTORE i1 
ISTORE i2 

LDC_W OBJREF
ILOAD i1  
INVOKEVIRTUAL 
OUT

LDC_W OBJREF
ILOAD i2   
INVOKEVIRTUAL abs
OUT
```

Where abs is a method to calculate the absolute value of an integer.

The first call of abs works fine and calculates the absolute value of `0xC0` properly, outputting `0x11`. However, the second call does not, and outputs `0x77`.

When I observe the stack frame instruction-by-instruction using the emulator, the second ILOAD ends up pushing `0x00000000` onto the stack instead of `0xffffffc0` like the first instruction. This means only the first call of the function actually outputs the proper value.

Does anyone know why it outputs `0x00000000` instead in subsequent calls?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this after a bit of investigation - there was an instruction within the method that was not properly used.